# How to simulate applicationWillResignActive message?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotifications

How can one simulate `applicationWillResignActive` to be called?

Locking screen, going to main menu, simulating phone call - none seemed to have helped.

In case I expect things that won't happen, let me tell you more: I subscribe to this message and when that happens hope that notification is sent to a method as listed below:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                 selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) 
                 name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:app];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid, it works for me. And locking the screen or hitting the home button will cause this notification to be posted.

*(One caveat to this is if your device does not support multitasking or if you have the "`Application does not run in background`" property set to yes in your `*info.plist`. In which case it will go straight to the "`UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`" notification)

So barring that there there are two possiblities:

1) Your `addObserver` code is not being called, ie. It's in the wrong method.

To test try this:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                           object:app];
NSLog(@"Observer added");
```

2) The observer method is not being called properly. Which requires the same method as the at selector.

To test try this:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive");
}
```

- Just as an additional point, if you want to see in action which of these notifications are called and when. In your AppDelegate class put the line `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));` in each of the `-application...` methods and it will log them when they are called. It's a nice hands on way to get to know them.

Comment: How to best locate the "Application does not run in background" property?

Comment: Click on your project in the pane all the way to the left. Then in the next pane over select your target (not your project). Then click the Info tab (for lack of a better description). And look in the 'Custom iOS Target Properties' subheading. It would be there. Or.. You can dig through your project folders and look for the file yourProjectNameHere-info.plist.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but I'm still curious was it the  "Application does not run in background" property that was the problem?